# get data from imu(GY9250) using arduino and calculate pitch yaw and roll

Tags: arduino

Im working on a Quadrotor project and i want to read data from my imu. i tried mpu6050 library but got just accelerometer and gyro data. i don't know how to access magnetometer data and use all these information to calculate pitch roll and yaw. the sensor Im using is GY9250. Im new in this field and i don't know mathematics.
ill be glad if someone can help me. thank you...
this is what i did:

```
accelgyro.getAcceleration(&ax, &ay, &az);
//Low Pass Filter
fXa = ax * alpha + (fXa * (1.0 - alpha));
fYa = ay * alpha + (fYa * (1.0 - alpha));
fZa = az * alpha + (fZa * (1.0 - alpha));

accelgyro.getRotation(&gx, &gy, &gz);

//pitch and roll
roll  = (atan2(-fYa, fZa)*180.0)/M_PI;
pitch = (atan2(-fXa, fZa)*180.0)/M_PI;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the image below you can see that MPU has Digital Motion Processor.

The embedded Digital Motion Processor (DMP) is located within the MPU-60X0 and offloads computation of motion processing algorithms from the host processor.

The DMP acquires data from accelerometers, gyroscopes, and additional 3rd party sensors such as magnetometers, and processes the data. The resulting data can be read from the DMP’s registers, or can be buffered in a FIFO.

The DMP has access to one of the MPU’s external pins, which can be used for generating interrupts.

[image]

Then I would suggest you to read this article: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050

And of course read this one too: http://www.varesano.net/projects/hardware/FreeIMU

Comment: tanx Ludo for the answer. im using: [link]http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-9150 BTW. i tried FreeIMU but it didnt work.i think its because of the registers. ill try the the arduino website code see what happen...

Comment: @lubo i can now axess the data but i dont know how to use them.better explain how to access the DMP. can u please help me?

Comment: There is a library called: i2cdevlib. You can find more information at this site: http://www.geekmomprojects.com/mpu-6050-dmp-data-from-i2cdevlib/ and the referenced github site contains even an Arduino example project: https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/master/Arduino/MPU6050/Examples/MPU6050_DMP6/MPU6050_DMP6.ino

Comment: @lubo thanx for your help.the link you gave me helped me a lot and solved my problem